# MS Access SQL Query Distinct Return Multiple Field

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

What I'd like to accomplish is querying a distinct field, `field1`, but return 2 fields' data. I'm using MS Access 2010 and `field1` is `Text` and 'field2' is `Date`.

Here is the current code:

```
select distinct (field1) from tblOne where year(ddate) = 2016
```

I tried searching online about Grouping but when I try to query it says the field is 'not aggregate' (most probably as it's a `Date` type?)

The distinct field should be 'field1'.

Sample DB:

```
field1     field2
------     --------
0000       1/1/2016
0000       1/1/2016
0000       1/1/2017
0001       1/1/2016
0002       1/1/2015

and the query should return this:
```

```
field1     maxfield2
------     --------
0000       1/1/2017 (the latest date)
0001       1/1/2016
0002       1/1/2015
```

Comment: Does your first query give you an error, or did that error come from something else?

Comment: "and return two fields from the data" - which two fields? field1 and field2 or two other random fields, you need to be clear if you want a quality answer

Comment: hi, the code 'select distinct(field1) from tblOne where year(ddate)=2016' works fine, but we need it to return 2 field value - field1(Text) and also field2(Date). thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't need distinct, distinct applies to all fields in the select not just the one immediately to the right of the distinct keyword. Distinct will get you a list of "distinct" rows, i.e, it just removes the duplicates.

You need a `GROUP BY`. This will show only one of each distinct combination of the grouped by fields, but then allows you to perform aggregates on other fields that are not grouped by. The aggregate you want here is `MAX`, as you said you wanted the latest—or greatest—date.

```
SELECT field1, MAX(field2) AS maxfield2
FROM tblOne
GROUP BY field1;
```

Comment: hmmm, this is weird. i remember replying to this comment previously. anyway, thanks for the sample, it works perfectly :)